# SailsJs Handlebar helper functions does not work

Tags: express, handlebars.js, sails.js

I am using Handlebars as templating engine for Sailsjs. Basic templating is working fine but I can't find out the way to use Handlebars helper function or even built in functions are not available.

I have managed to solve the issue with partials using following article.
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2414

I have also registered the helpers.js in config folder but I can't call any custom, built in blocks or iteration helper function.

Any pointers to solve the issue of helpers will be helpful.
Sailsjs verion - 0.11.4
Handlebars version - 4.0.5

I have registered the helper function in above file like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('help', function() {
    return "help22";
});
```

And I am calling the same in my template:

```
{{{help}}}
```

Any idea why it is not rendering?

Comment: I'm having exact the same issue, have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after few hours trying, I come up with a solution:

You can add this line to the end of config/helpers.js

```
module.exports = Handlebars.helpers;
```

Inside view.js:

```
module.exports.views = {
  engine: 'handlebars',
  layout: 'layout',
  partials: 'partials',
  helpers: require('./helpers')
};
```

It will work.

Comment: Thanks @haipham23, the first line made all the difference. I was looking for this for last couple of weeks. I had those changes in views.js as you have mentioned. Great!!!

Answer (score 0):

Above solution didn't work for me - I got error *"Handlebars is not defined"* because I didn't check this link- https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2414

I have had to add `Handlebars = require('handlebars');` in /config/helpers.js

Putting all together:

**Edit file /config/views.js**

```
module.exports.views = {
      engine: 'handlebars',
      extension: 'html',      // optional
      layout: 'layouts/main', // optional, will load /views/layouts/main.html
      partials: 'partials',   // optional, will load partials from /views/partials/
      helpers: require('./helpers') // <-- this is it
};
```

**Create file /config/helpers.js**

```
Handlebars = require('handlebars');
module.exports = Handlebars.helpers;

Handlebars.registerHelper('stringify', function(obj) {
    var json = {}, prop, tmp;
    for (prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            try {
                tmp = JSON.stringify(obj[prop]);
                json[prop] = obj[prop];
            } catch (e) {
                json[prop] = '[CAN NOT stringify]';
            }
        } 
    }
    return JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
});
```

In template I use `{{stringify entry}}`

Tested on **Sails v0.12.13**